# Exception in thread ... : null - trying to convert String from file to Integer

Tags: java, exception

like in the title , I'm stuck with this error for a while .I get the value from the file normally but when I try to convert it the error poops out. I read many topics ,but couldn't find any similar case to mine(with file) or any good tips. I tried adding an assert ,but it didn't help. The full description of error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:620)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:776)
at EnergyMeasure_needs_to_be_completed.main(EnergyMeasure_needs_to_be_completed.java:85)
```

Also I'm beginner (but I guess you already know that heh ;))

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class EnergyMeasure_needs_to_be_completed {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //int work_of_energy;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t Hi , this program will count how many kWh you're using");

        //asks about number of devices
        System.out.println("First of all, how many the same devices do you have in your house ?");
        int devices = input.nextInt();

        boolean bool = false;

        do {
            if (devices < 0) {
                System.out.println("You can't have less than 0 devices in your home!\nMake input once again :");
                devices = input.nextInt();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Okay, so you've got " + devices + " same devices.");
                bool = true;
                break;
            }
        }while(bool = true);

        //asks about time of use
        System.out.println("\nHow many hours you use them per day?");
        int time_use = input.nextInt();

        do {
            if (time_use > 24 || time_use < 0) {
                System.out.println("Wrong!\nMake input once again :");
                time_use = input.nextInt();
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("You use your devices for " + time_use + "h");
                bool = true;
                break;
            }
        }while(bool = true);
        /*else if(!input.hasNextInt()){
            System.out.println("Invalid input! \nEnter an integer : ");
            time_use = input.nextInt();
        } */

        //downloads value of power from file
        String power_dev; //path to the file

        power_dev = null; //reference to one line at a time

        try {
            FileReader fileReader = //reads text files in the default encoding
                    new FileReader("power_monitors");

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = //deal with a line at a time
                    new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((power_dev = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) { 
                System.out.println("\nThe power of your devices is " + power_dev + "W");
            }

            bufferedReader.close(); //close file

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) { //if file doesn't exist catch the except
            System.out.println("Unable to open file");
        }

        //assert power_dev != null; 

        int power_dec = Integer.parseInt(power_dev); //change the String ,to Integer
        int power_of_devices = power_dec * devices; //summary devices power
        //count the cost of work (W = P * t) [kWh]
        int work_of_energy = (power_of_devices / 1000) * time_use;

        System.out.println("The work of energy equals : " + work_of_energy);
    }
}
```

Comment: which line has error?

Comment: int power_dec = Integer.parseInt(power_dev);   i guess ,cuz before it everything runs OK

Comment: You wrote `while(bool = true)` in two places.  I’m pretty sure you meant to write `while (bool)`, rather than *assigning* a value to `bool` in the loop test.

Comment: You assign `null` to `power_dev` and then you parse it as an int. That will, of course, never work. First assign a decent value to `power_dev`.

Comment: Oh and you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names should be written in camelCase and class names in PascalCase.

Answer (score 0):

If you print power_dev, what do you get? What format is it? Because the readLine() returns a textual line, so depending on the source you are reading from, you might get more than an int.

Why not use the read() method? It returns an int, so you wouldn't have to parse power_dev.

Again, hard to answer your question without seeing the file or having a reproductible code, but my best guess is that power_dev returns null or something that can't be parsed by Integer.parseInt() method.

Comment: File contains only number 18 (also it returns 18) and the file itself is just a plain text document. It's not important how it reads value . I could just give a value to power_dev ,but that's not the case . I wanted to challenge my self and see if I could handle that .